# Error when exporting from BigQuery to MySQL

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to export a table from BigQuery to Google Cloud MySQL database.

I found this operator called `BigQueryToMySqlOperator` (documented here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/bigquery_to_mysql/index.html?highlight=bigquerytomysqloperator#module-airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.bigquery_to_mysql)

When I deploy the DAG containing this task onto cloud composer, the task always failed with the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1113, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1287, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1317, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/bigquery_to_mysql.py", line 166, in execute
    for rows in self._bq_get_data():
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/bigquery_to_mysql.py", line 138, in _bq_get_data
    response = cursor.get_tabledata(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery.py", line 2508, in get_tabledata
    return self.hook.get_tabledata(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery.py", line 1284, in get_tabledata
    rows = self.list_rows(dataset_id, table_id, max_results, selected_fields, page_token, start_index)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 412, in inner_wrapper
    raise AirflowException(
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: You must use keyword arguments in this methods rather than positional
```

I don't really understand why it is throwing out this error. Can anyone help me figuring out what went wrong or how should I export data from BigQuery to MySQL DB? Much thanks for your help!

EDIT: My operator code would basically look like this

```
transfer_data = BigQueryToMySqlOperator(
            task_id='task_id',
            dataset_table='origin_bq_table',
            mysql_table='dest_table_name',
            replace=True,
        )
```

Comment: Post your operator code

Comment: @Elad I've edited in my operator code
I believe the usage is standard enough

Comment: as alan explained in his answer this is probably a bug https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/17198

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like so,.Thank you for having a look still

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the stacktrace, you are most likely using [apache-airflow-providers-google==2.2.0](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/providers-google/2.2.0/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery.py#L1284).

> airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: You must use keyword arguments in
> this methods rather than positional

This error originates from the [GoogleBaseHook](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/providers-google/2.2.0/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py#L118), which can be traced back the BigQueryToMySqlOperator.

BigQueryToMySqlOperator > BigQueryHook > BigQueryConnection > BigQueryCursor > get_tabledata

The reason why you are getting the AirflowException is because [get_tabledata](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/providers-google/2.2.0/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/bigquery_to_mysql.py#L138)
is called as part of the execute method.

Unforuntately, the [test](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/providers-google/2.2.0/tests/providers/google/cloud/transfers/test_bigquery_to_mysql.py) for the operator is not comprehensive since it only checks whether or not the method was called was the correct parameters.

I think this will require a new release of the google provider where the cursor in BigQueryToMySqlOperator calls [list_rows](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/providers-google/2.2.0/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery.py#L1287-L1288) with keyword arguments instead of get_tabledata, which calls list_rows with positional arguments.

I have also made a [Github Issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/17198) in the Airflow repository.

Comment: Thank you so much Alan, it would seem that I'm stuck with this issue in the near future

Comment: One way you can workaround this would be to have a custom Operator that is essentially the same operator but with the get_tabledata replaced with the proper list_row method with named arguements.